# Is it possible to include the variables from .pl file rather than .pm?

Tags: perl

I am able to use the variables from imported .pm file. I can use the variables from .pl file. But when I add 'use strict' to the code it didnt work.

I tried the following

```
source.pl
{
    var = 22;
}
1;
```

main.pl

```
use strict;
my $ref = do "source.pl";
my ($mainvar) = @$ref{ qw(var) };
print "$mainvar\n";
```

here its printing the $mainvar as empty string. Please help

Comment: [take a look here](http://stein.cshl.org/genome_informatics/using_perl_modules/export.html)

Comment: What error message did it "didn't work" with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic Perl variable types:

- `my` - These are lexically scoped. This means that they fall in and out of existence depending upon where they're defined. Lexically scoped variables are only defined in the block they're in. If they're defined in a file, they're only accessible to that file.
- `our` - These are *package* variables. A *package* is just Perl creating a namespace that's specific to that area of the code (usually an entire file).

In Perl, when you're in a package, you can use the variables without any prefix. Otherwise, you need to prefix variable (and subroutine names) with their package name. Think of `File::Find's`$File::Find::dir`. That's the`$dir`variable in the`File::Find` package.

When you `use strict;`, you must either declare your variable with either `our` (for package variables or `my` (for lexically scoped variables, or use the full package name of that variable:

#### source.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $var = 22;
```

#### test.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

do "source.pl";
our $var;     #Merely a declaration -- Doesn't change the value

my $local_var = $var;
print "$local_var\n";
```

You could have done this too:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw(once);

do "source.pl";
my $local_var = $main::var;  #Specified full package name of variable
print "$local_var\n";
```

I had to use `no warnings qw(once);` to remove the warning that `$main::var` is only used once.